# can I host my online C compiler on google-app-engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, host

My whole code is written in Java(jsps,and servlets,the jsps do contain some HTML tags,and I used CSS for the designing). For compiling the C code, I am using a native C compiler (gcc). So, can I host my web application on google-app-engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe GAE allows you to call external programs. At any rate, GAE doesn't allow you to save to the filesystem, so GCC probably wouldn't be able to run anyway.

Comment: And that's assuming gcc is even installed on the GAE nodes. You can pretty much pick your reason why GAE apps can't call gcc.

Comment: There's a thousand-and-one good reasons that it is 100% unpossible.

Comment: @Zhehao Mao btw, would you know any other engines that I could use to host my web application for free?

Comment: I don't really know any good ones for Java hosting. This site [here](http://servlets.com/isps/servlet/ISPViewAll) seems to have a list, but I don't know which ones are good and which are bad.

Comment: Most shared webhosts will probably not let you run gcc from your application on their server. If that's what you want to do, you may consider investing in a Virtual Private Server. [Linode](http://linode.com), [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com), and [Slicehost](http://slicehost.com) are always good choices.